# Error al instalar módulos con pip (python) en Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

Tengo un problema con las dos versiones de python (2.7 y 3.6), al intentar instalar módulos con el comando "pip" y "pip3".

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Este es el error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build- 
yuno57tn/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install -- 
record /tmp/pip-p5is4qs3-record/install-record.txt --single-version- 
externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 
1 in /tmp/pip-build-yuno57tn/mysqlclient/
```

Antes me mandaba este error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/v9/5n8070c96854w3mhd9knc73w0000gn/T/pip-build- 
zZTmYY/fbprophet/
```

Después instale "libmysqlclient-dev" y actualice el modulo 'setuptools' y me mando el error anterior. ¿Alguien sabe porque?. Gracias.

Comment: Sé que es una chapuza, pero yo a veces cuando he tenido problemas y errores al intentar módulos, he conseguido hacerlos funcionar copiando las librerías directamente a la raíz de mi programa .py